# Using jQuery to edit Google Form iframe

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, google-forms

I'm trying to edit the look of a Google Form iframe on a website. I can add CSS using one of the site's stylesheets, but Google's own is embedded in the head, within the iframe, so I can't override, just augment.  But, of course, I want to override it.  So I'm trying to .appendTo a link to my own specific stylesheet in the head in the iframe, but this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="http://companeros.ca/wp-content/themes/organic_non-profit/GFstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">').appendTo('#content iframe html head');
});
```

Isn't working.

Is this possible?  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You need to add more details. You cannot edit inside of an iframe. This ability is restricted for the sake of security in all browsers.

Comment: Yeah, more reading about generally editing an iframe, shows me that it's not possible.  I can see why, as the reason why I'm using this iframe is to load a secure form; it wouldn't do to have me messing with it.  If anybody else rads this and has a better/different idea, I'd love to hear it. Thanks, C